# Change the date of a git commit without leaving traces

Tags: git, commit

I have a work I needed to deliver today by 11h30 am. So works committed and pushed before that hour are accepted. Apparently, I only got to found the bug 10 minutes after, it's such a simple thing!

I can't stop thinking about it and I did some researched and found it's possible to amend the commit date. The fact is, will someone be able to found I made that change?

How can I do it? I'm currently using eclipse, if it's easier.

Big Thanks for your help.

Edit: The git is hosted on a local server. Evaluators have admin rights.

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? (I am assuming it is.) Even if it is possible, if someone finds out, you could end up getting into trouble with the university's academic honesty policy. Since you were only ten minutes late, maybe an email to the professor explaining the bug you found and the proposed commit would be a great way to show him or her that you performed your own code review and were able to find an error. I still think this is a good question though.

Comment: It's a dilema, let's see how it works :p

Comment: If you try to do this, I sincerely hope you're caught.

Comment: I don't understand why. I mean, are you happy to wish other's failure? I would like to see the same happening to you, I bet you would wish you had more 10 minutes, but you didn't. When it happens to others, it's easy to talk about, uh? Things just don't work so good under pressure, you should already know that, unless you're one of those guys who like to make things run slower.
But I don't need to say anything else, one day you will have the same feeling and remember me. In that time, I hope you also have no chance of fixing it. Good Night!

Comment: @PedroBarros, you "don't understand why" we're advocating for honesty and academic integrity? Why we're in favour of students having an even playing field? Of earning grades fairly? Of cheaters being caught and reprimanded? Why cheating completely misses the point of pursuing an education? That's mind-boggling.

Comment: The fact, which seems you forgot is, I know how to do it, I just didn't had time. Does "your said" academic grades also count on that?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that but it should help you!

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2000-01-01T12:00:00" git commit --date==2000-01-01T12:00:00 --amend
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't stop thinking about it and I did some researched and found it's possible to amend the commit date. The fact is, will someone be able to found I made that change?

Yes, they will be able to tell that you modified the commit.

Commit hashes are computed from several pieces of information, one of which is the commit's timestamp. If you change the commit's timestamp you'll get a different hash.

Comment: But is it hard to tell that? I guess evaluator will only check the date.
Is it easy to check if the hash is different?
If not, I guess it's work to take the risk.

Comment: It's *extremely* easy to check. The hash is the commit's identity, and your new push is sure to get logged. Plus, with hooks they could easily have an alert if you try to cheat. Better to be honest and safe, like the commenter above suggests.

Comment: But last time I was evaluated, he only accessed my account and clicked the commit with date before the one stated. He didn't checked, I don't think he does with so much people to evaluate. How do you proceed to check that?

Comment: You asked how to modify a commit timestamp "without leaving traces". I told you it's not possible. Now, in addition to arguing with me about my answer, you've stopped asking technical questions ("is it possible…") and started asking impossible ones ("will I get caught…"). I've already described a few ways you *could* get caught. I'm not interested in arguing with somebody who won't listen, and I'm not interested in helping you cheat. At this point I half hope you try it and *do* get caught.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to start a discussion. I was just asking how do i find out myself that by comparing the hashes. But as you are taking it the wrong way, never mind. Plus, you should re-read my answer-to-you-comments and see it says "How do you check that" instead of "will I get caught", so _don't_ put words in my mouth that are made in your head.

Comment: You didn't use the words "will I get caught?", but by moving on from the *technical question of how Git works* and moving on to *what your evaluator checked last time* your question is *no longer* on-topic on Stack Overflow. Your line of questioning very clearly suggests the question "will I get caught?", which (again!) is *impossible to answer* (we have no idea what your evaluator might or might not check, what your school logs, etc.) and (for most of us, even if you're struggling with this concept) unethical.

Answer (score 1):

If your teachers are clever, they'll use the reflog to which you don't have access on the server. At least, that's what I do with my students ;-).

And if you try to be more clever than them by tweaking your commit date, you'll likely get caught.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already made an "honest" commit and pushed it to the server, then no, you cannot really amend the commit. If you *do* perform a `commit --amend`, an attempt to push to the server will result in an error stating that you are "behind" the server's copy of your branch, and that you must do a fetch. When you do that fetch, you'll just get back the original commit you tried to amend, and you will have to merge that with your "new" commit.

Whether to bend the rules or not is a personal decision, and I'm not going to lecture you about it - a 10 minute fib is hardly the crime of the century. *However*, I would counsel you to weigh the risks and benefits of trying to do this. Most schools take academic integrity pretty seriously, and I am guessing that the punishment you would face if caught is far greater then the penalty of getting this one homework assignment not done on time. So even if you have only, say, a 10% chance of getting caught, it still probably is not a smart thing to do. I think it is in your own best interest to just eat this one. No matter what you decide to do, I wish you the best of luck.